# Is it possible to emit a message from jscript that will be visible in DebugViewer?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that app calls via windows scripting host. Is it possible to somehow send a debug message from this jscript code so i can view it in DebugViewer (`dbgview.exe` that catches messages sent via `OutputDebugString()` )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** want this, it's possible via PowerShell. This is a VBScript example, which you can probably adapt to JScript easily:

```
Option Explicit

OutputDebugString "some message"

Sub OutputDebugString(message)
  Dim WshShell, cmd
  message = Replace(message, "'",   "' + ""'"" + '")
  message = Replace(message, vbCr, "' + ""`r"" + '")
  message = Replace(message, vbLf, "' + ""`n"" + '")
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  cmd = "Add-Type -Name C -NS """" -MemberDefinition '[DllImport(""kernel32.dll"")]public static extern void OutputDebugString(String s);'"
  cmd = cmd & "; [C]::OutputDebugString('" & message & "')"
  cmd = "PowerShell """ & Replace(cmd, """", "\""") & """" ' \""
  WshShell.Run cmd, 0, True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Script Host's JScript has the [`Debug.writeln`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azawx9th.aspx) and [`Debug.write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9k4wete.aspx) methods for sending output to the script debugger, although I don't know if DebugView can catch these strings.

Comment: DebugView can't catch these strings :(.

Answer (score 0):

Investigation shows that it's no build-in ways for both ECMAScript and Windows Scripting Host to emit messages into "debug output". There is also no way to call WinAPI functions from Windows SCripting Host.